# Using Ransack in Rails, how can I prevent extensive processing from a user defined search query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ransack

I've set up a page in my rails application for a user to define criteria to perform a search using Ransack.  However, I've noticed that if I build a short criteria list such as, `first_name = 'John'`, that the entire server's processing will get close to 100% and it will slow the server down dramatically.  What's the best way to resolve this?  Do I need to configure my SQL Server to prevent using that much processing power? Or is there something I can do in the Ransack configuration?  If I need to provide some code from a certain area of the app please let me know and I can add it.